# teechart freeze on Windows X64

Tags: teechart, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a freeze of my application with the following code, with TChart TPointSeries on Windows 64 bits.

I've simplified as much as I could my project to reproduce the problem.
I only have a **form** with a **TButton** and a **TeeChart** with a **TPointSeries**. On the button OnClick event I have the following code:

```
{******************************************************************************}
procedure TForm2.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  X1, Y1, X2 : double ;

begin
  X1 := 10.5 ;
  Y1 := 289 ;
  X2 := ( 10.5 * 9.81 * 821 ) / ( 821 * 9.81 ) ;

  Series1.AddXY( X1, Y1 ) ;
  Series1.AddXY( X2, Y1 ) ;

end;
{******************************************************************************}
```

The problem occurs only with project built for Windows 64 bits bits, everything works well for Windows 32 bits.

The problem doesn't occur if I change the values of X2 formula, or if I replace the formula by it's result.

I need to have this code working for any values of X2 formula, as it is part of an engineering software with formula members as variables.

Can someone help for a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Usually, this happens because some 32 bits package/lib is used in the project.Did you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added it to the public tracker: [#2059](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=2059).
Here a possible workaround:

```
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items.Automatic:=False;
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items.Clear;
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items.Add(X1, FormatFloat(Chart1.Axes.Bottom.AxisValuesFormat, X1));
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items.Add(X2, FormatFloat(Chart1.Axes.Bottom.AxisValuesFormat, X2));
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(X1-0.5, X2+0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Yeray for your solution, it works well.

As I have and several charts, and several series on the same chart in my original project, I coded the following workaround procedure. I call it for all axes with Automatic status, used by at least one serie. This solves the problem in any case.

```
procedure ChartBug2059_Workaround( AAxis : TChartAxis ; 
                                   AAxisMin, AAxisMax : double ) ;
begin
    if IsAEqB( AxisMin, AxisMax ) then
    begin
        AAxis.Automatic:=False;
        AAxis.SetMinMax(AxisMin-0.5, AxisMax+0.5);
    end
    else
      AAxis.Automatic:=true;
end;
```